# Open new tab in browser window (opened with window.open)

Tags: javascript, tabs, window, window.open

I have a new window opened via window.open method and in that window in content I have a link with "target=_blank".

When clicked the link opens new tab in parent window instead of the one that content was in. I also noticed that for that window (created with window.open) the Ctrl+T shortcut (to open blank tab, Firefox) does not work.

I checked window.open specs and I didn't find any option that would allow this behavior.

```
var a = window.open("http://www.google.pl", 
"Test",
"width=640,height=480,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=yes"); 
a.focus();
```

Setting toolbar=yes makes it work in Firefox. Any idea how to make it work in chrome?

Comment: There's generally no way to control this from page code; it's ultimately a user-controlled behavior.

Comment: What do you mean? How user can controll where _blank will be opened?

Comment: They can control it via browser settings ("Always open new windows in browser tabs" for example).

Comment: The one you mentioned is not related (window correctly opens). Are there any related?

Comment: Again, ultimately the user is in control, both for the behavior of `window.open()` and for windows implied by `target` attributes. You can find ways to make things work sometimes, in some browsers, but there are no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

Could you show some code?

else; try with javascript:

`function OpenNew(){
window.open("http://www.google.se", "_blank");
}`

Rgds

Comment: Hmm. It's not about that. I have a window opened with window.open() and it loads a web page where there is a link with _blank target. And after clicking a link a new tab opens in parent window instead of the popup.

Comment: I edited the question and added code that partialy solves the problem.